# Why my wordpress admin panel shows only English Language in setting?

Tags: language

I am not able to see the list of language in admin panel after uploading in server. But in my local system i can see the list of default languages.

I have tried declaring `WP_CONTENT_DIR` constant but didn't help.

Can any one one help me ?

Comment: This is 4.6.1, same on local and server.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem switching to the unedited default Theme (Twenty Sixteen) for a moment using the WP dashboard